Choice of group action on Sylow subgroups
This question is in relation to exercises of the form "show that a group of order $n$ is not simple."
Suppose $G$ is a finite group, and $p$ is a prime dividing the order of $G$. Generally, I see people considering the conjugation action of $G$ on the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups, but I was wondering if it would be more strategic to actually consider the left action of $G$ on the cosets of $G/N_G(P)$ where $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup.
All of the important properties of the conjugation action are preserved by the left action:

the induced homomorphism is $\psi:G\rightarrow S_{n_p}$
the induced homomorphism is injective. Assuming by contradiction $G$ is simple, $\ker(\psi)=G$ or $\{e\}$ by the first isomorphism theorem. The conjugation-induced homomorphism must be injective because if $G$ was the kernel, $G$ would normalize the $p$-Sylow subgroups which is a contradiction. Similarly, the left action-induced homomorphism must be injective because if $G$ was the kernel, every element in $G$ would be in the normalizer of $P$, which is a contradiction.
Both of the actions are transitive

However, the reason I say that the left action is more useful is because you also get way more information about the kernel, which is a normal subgroup: $\ker(\psi)\subset N_G(P)$, $[G: \ker(\psi)]\mid n_p!$ and $n_p\mid[G: \ker(\psi)]$. Is there something I'm getting wrong/missing? Everyone seems to use the conjugation action, so maybe the two are actually the same.

$\ker\psi$ is the intersection of all the conjugates of $N_G(P)$. I don't understand why you say this is trivial, in your second bullet point.

@Kan't in the context of "prove a group $G$ of order $n$ is not simple" OP is assuming $G$ is simple, so $N_G(P)\neq G$ and the kernel is not all of $G$, hence would be trivial due to the assumed simplicity of $G$.

Ah sure, I had missed that, @ArturoMagidin.

The kernel of your action is exactly the same as the kernel of the action on the Sylows by conjugation, and maps to the same symmetric group. So you are not getting "way more information about the kernel". You get exactly the same information about it.
The usual action is on the Sylow subgroups by conjugation. That gives you a morphism $G\to S_{n_p}$ as well, so the kernel has index dividing $n_p!$. Because the action is transitive on the Sylow subgroups, you likewise get that the index is a multiple of $n_p$. So the numerical information you have extracted is the same.
Finally, the kernel of the action on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication is well-known to be the core of $H$, the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$, which is equal to
$$\mathrm{core}(H) = \bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}.$$
So the kernel of your action is precisely the core of $N_G(P)$. However, note that in general we have
$$N_G(xHx^{-1}) = xN_G(H)x^{-1}$$
for any subgroup $H$ and any element $x\in G$. Indeed, if $g\in N_G(H)$, then for any $h\in H$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
(xgx^{-1})(xhx^{-1})(xgx^{-1})^{-1} &= xgx^{-1}xhx^{-1}xg^{-1}x^{-1}\\
&= xghg^{-1}x^{-1} \in xHx^{-1},
\end{align*}$$
because $ghg^{-1}\in H$. That means that $xgx^{-1}\in N_G(xHx^{-1})$, so $xN_G(H)x^{-1}\subseteq N_G(xHx^{-1})$. Applying this again we have
$$x^{-1}N_G(xHx^{-1})x \subseteq N_G(x^{-1}(xHx^{-1})x) = N_G(H),$$
so $N_G(xHx^{-1})\subseteq xN_G(H)x^{-1}$, proving equality.
So what is the kernel of the action by conjugation? An element $g\in G$ lies in the kernel of the action by conjugation if and only if it normalizes every Sylow subgroup. But since each Sylow subgroup is a conjugate of $P$ and vice versa, that means that $g$ lies in the kernel of the action by conjugation if and only if
$$\begin{align*}
x\in \bigcap_{Q\in\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)}N_G(Q) &\iff x\in\bigcap_{g\in G}N_G(gPg^{-1})\\
&\iff x\in \bigcap_{g\in G}gN_G(P)g^{-1}\\
&\iff x\in\mathrm{core}(N_G(P))\\
&\iff x\in\ker(\psi).
\end{align*}$$
So while the action you define might be different, the kernels are the same.

Thank you so much for the detailed response! I have two clarifying questions to make sure I am understanding your arguments. First, to verify the numerical information, you say that because the action is transitive, you get that the index is a multiple of $n_p$- this follows from the Orbit Stabilizer theorem? Second, you say "ℎ^{-1}^{−1}∈^{−1}, because ^{−1}∈." Did you mean because $ghg^{-1}\in H$? Once again, thanks for your help!

@fatlips22 The latter was a typo now corrected; yes, it should have been "because $ghg^{-1}\in H$". The first: because the orbit of $P$ has length $n_p$, the size of the orbit times the size of the stabilizer equals the size of the group. This applies to the image of $G$ in $S_{n_p}$ (which has size the index of the kernel), so the image has size a multiple of the length of the orbit, which is $n_p$.

Makes sense- thank you!
